# How to hide a label automatically after 5 seconds in Eclipse RCP application?

Tags: java, user-interface, swt, eclipse-rcp

I am trying to create a label in RCP application which which is initially not visible. When I click Save button, it becomes visible. Again, it should be invisible with 5 seconds.

For this purpose I wrote this following code:

```
saveButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {

            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println(textName.getText());
                String text = textName.getText();
                tree.getSelection()[0].setText(text);
                String nodeId = ((TreeStructure) tree.getSelection()[0]
                        .getData()).getNodeId();
                // update the database
                UpdateTree updateTree = new UpdateTree();
                updateTree.renameNode(text, nodeId);
                label.setBounds(xForFirstButton, yIndexForButtons
                        + Constants.BUTTON_BUFFER, Constants.BUTTON_WIDTH,
                        Constants.BUTTON_HEIGHT);
                label.setVisible(true);

                AbstractAction myAction = new AbstractAction() {

                    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        label.setVisible(false);
                    }
                };

                Timer myTimer = new Timer(5000, myAction);
                myTimer.start();
            }
```

But, this code, while running gives this following error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4441)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4356)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4327)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.checkWidget(Widget.java:367)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.setVisible(Control.java:3781)
    at com.app.editor.views.EditorView$2$1.actionPerformed(EditorView.java:183)
    at javax.swing.Timer.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.Timer$DoPostEvent.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Can please anyone point what is the issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All code which changes the UI must run in the UI thread - `Timer` is running the code in a different thread.

Instead of `Timer` use:

```
Display.getDefault().timerExec(milliseconds, runnable);
```

Comment: Note that you will have to check if the label you about to hide is not yet disposed within the runnable. Otherwise you may cause a widget-disposed exception.

Answer (score 0):

To update you ui from a thread which is not the ui thread you have to use this:

```
Display.getDefault().syncExec(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
           // Update UI here
     }
});
```

`syncExec` will perform your actions within the ui thread of your rcp application.

This is similar to the `invokeLater()` method in Swing.